# How can I structure my directory when using a single header.php file?

Tags: php, directory

I'd like to use a single header.php file that I will call on all my pages. I'd like to know if this directory structure is correct:

```
      /public_html
          index.php
          header.php
          /page1
              index.php
          /page2
              index.php
```

Inside page 1 and 2 I will call the header.php file using the include function :

Will I be able to call the header.php file even though it is located one level above page1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

A better practice would be to store all the common files ( like header.php) in folder `includes` , as shown below:

```
/public_html
      index.php
      /includes
           header.php
      /page1
          index.php
      /page2
          index.php
```

You can access this file ( `header.php` ) from `/page1/index.php` simply by doing this

```
include '../includes/header.php';
```

From `/public_html/index.php`, you just do this:

```
include 'includes/header.php;
```

**ADDED FEW THINGS HERE:**

```
define('BASE_URL', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/");
```

You may use this to define the server name. Then you can include your files using this constant as below:

```
include BASE_URL . 'public_html/includes/header.php';
```

This is equivalent to :

```
include 'YourServer/public_html/includes/header.php';
```

This way, you don't have to worry about the level of directory to be jumped using `..`

Comment: Thanks. by "../includes/header.php';", should I actually write ".." ? Is this the way to write an absolute path?

Comment: See the answer again. I've added few things about generating base url.

Comment: Thanks. I also find this      <?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/public_html/header.php";
   include_once($path);
?>    It works great too. Would you recommend this method?

Comment: You can use any of them. But when you need to give the path for assets like images, css files or other then you should use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`